# Windows 8 application deployment

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I developed a Windows 8 C# application using Visual Studio Express 2012 RC. I can run it on my pc. However, I want to create an executable so that my friends can also try the application. When I click the .exe file under bin/Release folder it says:

> This application can only run in the context of an app container.

How can i create an app container manually or using Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: Would this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464929.aspx help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deploy a Metro App to the Desktop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451536/how-to-deploy-a-metro-app-to-the-desktop)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/toolsforwinapps/thread/74e053e0-05ca-4ee3-a2d3-bef2901c0016/).

> You need a developer license to develop and test Metro style apps
>   prior to certifying and deploying through the store. Visual Studio
>   2012 will automatically request a developer license when it is run for
>   the first time. To get a developer license without Visual Studio run
>   the show-WindowsDeveloperLicenseRegistration function in powershell:

```
C:\Windows\system32>powershell 
Windows PowerShell Copyright (C) 2012
Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Windows\system32> Show-WindowsDeveloperLicenseRegistration
```

> For
>   information on developer licenses see: [Get a developer license (Metro
>   style apps)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974578.aspx) To deploy the app, build a package in Visual Studio from
>   the Store.Build Pacakage menu.  Build it for local use.  Copy the
>   resulting package to the target machine and run the included
>   Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 file. See also [Sharing an app package locally.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh975356%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) 
>   --Rob