# Testing Windows Store Application on other machines

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I want to test my windows 8 metro application on others PC such as my MS Surface or my friend's PC. but when I run it, I get following error:

> This application can only run in the context of an AppContainer.

i searched a lot and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451536/how-to-deploy-a-metro-app-to-the-desktop) but this topic for 2011 and VS 2011, so the solution does not work anymore.

please advice me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution from the referenced thread should still work, especially point 2.

Right-clicking the project and choosing "Store"->"Create App Package..." (deselect uploading to the store) will create a folder with a package for your app and the dependencies.
In the same folder there is a PowerShell script. When run, it will probably ask you to change your ExecutionPolicy the first time, but then it will install the app just like a regular app that was installed from the store.